# How can I embed my application into MFC without loosing my App.xaml?

Tags: wpf, mfc, interop

I've created a very nice (if I do say so myself) WPF app. Well, my client now wants me to embed that app into an existing MFC project. No problem I know how to do that. What I don't know how to do is ensure that my App.Xaml still works. My global resource dictionary and even my view model bindings are handled through App.Xaml, and since I'm not just exposing my project as a control to the MFC application, the App.Xaml doesn't get initialized. Is there a way I can initialize it manually?

Help. O_O

Comment: Just do `var app = new App();` then `app.InitializeComponent();` in the constructor of your View.

Comment: I believe that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do

```
var app = new App(); 
app.InitializeComponent();
```

in the constructor of your View